# Cannot install the latest Eclipse Subversive Plug-In

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I am getting errors when using the option to compare with the latest version from the repo as per this bug report:

[Compare with" dialogs exit with "A path under version control is needed for this operation](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=485622)

I have Subversive - SVN Team Provider version 4.0.5. I thought if I upgraded to the latest version, the error would be resolved.

I installed the latest version as per this link:

https://www.eclipse.org/subversive/installation-instructions.php

The install was successful, but when I go to Help/Eclipse Marketplace/Installed, I still see version 4.0.5. I tried to remove it, and I get an error indicating that certain core plugins are required.

Below are the items that remain after I uninstall this plugin version 4.0.5.

[image]

How I can force install the latest version of Eclipse SVN?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version per that installation-instructions link is for 4.8.0, not 4.0.5, using https://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/4.8/release/latest/. The bug report mentions it was fixed in version 4.6.

Comment: No matter what I do, version 4.0.5 will remain. I tried to uninstall 4.0.5 but it was not removed completely. I installed 4.8.0 and it is not taking effect.